# Getting null pointer exception from ws.url

Tags: java, spring-boot, playframework, get

```
@Inject
private WSClient ws;

@Override
public void getTerminalDetails(String terminalId, String institutionId) {

    String url = "http://localhost:8089/getDetails";
    WSRequest request = ws.url(url);
    CompletionStage<WSResponse>  wsResponse = request.get();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>           at service.impl.TerminalDetailsServiceImpl.getTerminalDetails(TerminalDetailsServiceImpl.java:25)

Line no 25 is:

```
WSRequest request = ws.url(url);
```

Can someone help me that what I am getting wrong. I am newbie at Play framework having migrated from SpringBoot.

Comment: Do you have an @Inject constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I hadn't declared an inject construct as pointed by VM4

The code block should be like this:

```
public class DetailsServiceImpl implements DetailsService,WSBodyReadables {

private final WSClient ws;
private final Config config;

@Inject
public DetailsServiceImpl(WSClient ws, Config config) {
    this.ws = ws;
    this.config = config;
}


@Override
public GetDetailsResonse getDetails(String param1) {
    WSRequest request = ws.url("URL here").setRequestTimeout(Duration.of(5000, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
    CompletionStage<JsonNode> response = request.get().thenApply(wsResponse -> wsResponse.getBody(json()));
    log.info(response.toString());
    GetDetailsResonse getDetailsResonse = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false).convertValue(response.toCompletableFuture().join(), GetDetailsResonse.class);
    return getDetailsResonse ;
}
```